# 403 error while trying to access WSO2MB(3.2.0) management console

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

i was trying to access management console , after deploying  WSO2MB . I kept all the default configuration . Used admin user to access console , i get 403 error.

Server version is WSO2 Message Broker-3.2.0

Is there any settings to be ewnabled to access WSO2MB ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following property at the bottom of `Owasp.CsrfGuard.Carbon.properties` file found in /repository/conf/security.

This might be an issue with CSRF security and in some java versions it has an issue.